# Undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::setPath()

Tags: laravel, model, eloquent, carousel

I am trying to call my table called "Carousel". But it's getting an error.
I already created for my Model. I am using php myadmin.

Error Message :

> undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::setPath()

Carousel model

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Carousel extends Model
{ 

}
```

Controller

```
function getsearchCarousel(Request $req){

    if($req->has('searchcar')){
        $data = Carousel::where('carouselName','like',$req->input('searchcar').'%')->select('id','carouselName, carouselPhoto');
        $data->setPath($req->url()."?searchcarousel=".$req->searchcar);
        return view('Admin.Page.Carousel.carousel')->with('data', $data);
    }
    else{
        return redirect('/Admin/Page/carousel');
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is that "setPath" method defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `->get()` part

```
$data = Carousel::where('carouselName','like',$req->input('searchcar').'%')->select('id','carouselName, carouselPhoto')->get();
```

So, provided there is a setPath function defined in your model, now you'll find it, because actually you are trying to get it from the queryBuilder.

Comment: But **->get()** return instance of **\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection** not **Corusel** model ???

Answer (score 0):

In your code you dont get data in db. For get data in db you must be use after your code `->get()` or `->first()` method.

```
$carusels = Carousel::where('carouselName','like',$req->input('searchcar').'%')
    ->select('id','carouselName, carouselPhoto')
    ->get();
```

This case `carusels` is instance of `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` and you you must be use forecah to get separate $carusel

```
foreach($carusels as $data) {
    $data->setPath($req->url()."?searchcarousel=".$req->searchcar);       
}
```

and in your `Courusel` model define `setPath` method.

Also you can get single data using `->first`

```
$carusels = Carousel::where('carouselName','like',$req->input('searchcar').'%')
    ->select('id','carouselName, carouselPhoto')
    ->first();
$data->setPath($req->url()."?searchcarousel=".$req->searchcar);
```